# How to match a list of strings to another file and print the preceding line for multiple matches?

Tags: bash

I have a file of peptide sequences in `peptides.txt` that I would like to match to my protein database `human_proteins.fasta`. I would like to match the peptide list to the protein database and fetch the protein ID which is in the preceding line. Some of the peptides have multiple matches to the protein database.

Ultimately, I would like to produce a table/dataframe like this:

| Peptide | No. of matches | Sequence ID | Protein Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 2 | ENST0001 | AAAAABCFMED |
| AAAAA | 2 | ENST0002 | AAAAAXXX |

The first few lines of my hypothetical protein database `human_proteins.fasta` look like this:

> >ENST0001
> AAAAABCFMED
> >ENST0002
> AAAAAXXX
> >ENST0003
> MGRVSGLVPSR

`peptides.txt` looks like this:

```
AAAAA
LSSPATLNSR
HETLTSLNLEK
GGGGNFGPGPGSNFR
VSEQGLIEILK
DFLAGGIAAAISK
```

I am using the following command in bash

```
while read line; do printf $line grep -B 1 $line ../databases/human_proteins.fasta < peptides.txt
```

and I am able to get output like this:

```
>ENST0001
AAAAABCFMED
>ENST0002
AAAAAXXX
```

However, I am having trouble processing the output into a table. Is there a nice solution in unix/bash that can solve this?

Comment: Can you provide `peptides.txt` as well?

Comment: `the output into a table` I do not understand how to change the `output like this:` into a table like above? What should be in column 2? Or do you want only an example with two columns - the 3rd and 4th?

Comment: @KamilCuk I would like to match peptides to a protein database and output a table or txt file with the peptide sequence, no. of matches, protein sequence id, protein sequence. I only showed 2 rows as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it with python:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

seq = {}
peptide = {}
matches = {}
result = []

with open("human_proteins.fasta") as f:
    while True:
        id = f.readline().rstrip().lstrip(">")
        if not id: break
        protein = f.readline().rstrip()
        seq[id] = protein
        matches[id] = 0

with open("peptides.txt") as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.rstrip()
        for id in seq:
            protein = seq[id]
            if re.match(i, protein):
                peptide[id] = i
                matches[id] += 1

for id in seq:
    if matches[id]:
        result.append([peptide[id], matches[id], id, seq[id]])

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.columns = ["Peptide", "No. of matches", "Sequence ID", "Protein Sequence"]

print(df)
```

Output for provided files:

```
  Peptide  No. of matches Sequence ID Protein Sequence
0   AAAAA               1    ENST0001      AAAAABCFMED
1   AAAAA               1    ENST0002         AAAAAXXX
```

Please note I have assumed the column of `No. of matches` means the count of the same `Protein Sequence`. If it should be the count of the same `Peptide` (then the values above will be 2), please let me know.

**[EDIT]**
If the column of `No. of matches` referres to the count of `peptide` found in the fasta file, here is an alternative:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

seq = {}
peptide = {}
matches = {}
result = []

with open("human_proteins.fasta") as f:
    while True:
        id = f.readline().rstrip().lstrip(">")
        if not id: break
        protein = f.readline().rstrip()
        seq[id] = protein

with open("peptides.txt") as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.rstrip()
        matches[i] = 0
        for id in seq:
            protein = seq[id]
            if re.match(i, protein):
                peptide[id] = i
                matches[i] += 1

for id in peptide:
    result.append([peptide[id], matches[peptide[id]], id, seq[id]])

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.columns = ["Peptide", "No. of matches", "Sequence ID", "Protein Sequence"]

print(df)
```

Comment: thanks! I will try this out. The count refers to the count of the same peptide (2 in this case).

Comment: to clarify, the count should refer to the number of times the peptide was found in human_protein.fasta

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have added an alternative to count the peptides in the fasta file. I hope it will meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for testing. Good to know it works. BR.